# IIF statement in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, iif

Does `IIF` statement exists in all version of SQL Server ?

I have checked a tutorial on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145994(SQL.90).aspx).

But when I tried to run this code on my machine

```
DECLARE @newDate datetime
SET @newDate =  CONVERT(varchar, {fn NOW()}, 111)
SELECT IIF(@newDate > '2010/12/2', 'Greater', 'smaller')
```

But I am getting error of "Incorrect syntax near '>'."

Can someone provide me an example in SQL Server 2005 for the existence of the `IIF` statement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That `IIF` statement only exists in **MDX** - the query language for SQL Server **Analysis** Services - the datawarehousing side of SQL Server.

Plain T-SQL does **not** have an `IIF` statement.

The best you can do in T-SQL is use the `CASE.... WHEN... THEN...` statement.

Comment: UPDATE: SQL Server 2012 now has an IIF Statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx

Comment: @Somantra: true - but that was not known back in Dec'2010, and the OP was asking about SQL Server 2005.

Comment: The title says 2005, but his first question asked "Does IIF statement exists in all version of SQL Server ?". Hopefully someone finds something useful in this post in the future. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You're better off using a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression:

```
DECLARE @newDate datetime
SET @newDate =  CONVERT(varchar, {fn NOW()}, 111)
SELECT CASE WHEN @newDate > '20101202' THEN 'Greater' ELSE 'smaller' END
```

Please also note that I've switched your date literal to a safe format - '2010/12/2' could be interpreted by SQL server as either the 12th February or 2nd December.

Answer (score -2):

```
   IIF([Add DVP Month].DevelopmentMonth>[Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS,
       1,
   IIF([STATUS]<>'1',
       1, 
   IIF([Add DVP Month].PLANTYPE = 'A' and [Add DVP Month].newUsedProgram = 'U' and [Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS = 60 and [Add DVP Month].COVMILES = 100000 and [Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2010#,
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2012#, 
       [EPMthd.PCM2],   
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2010#, 
   [EPMthd.PCM1], 
   [EPMthd.PCM0])
   ),
   IIF([Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS = 999,[EPMthd.2],
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2012#, [EPMthd.2],
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2010#, [EPMthd.1],
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt >= #1/31/2008#, 
   IIF([EPMthd.0] is null, 
       [EPMthd.8], 
       [EPMthd.0]
      ),
   IIF([Add DVP Month].postedDt < #1/31/2008#, 
   IIF([EPMthd.8] is null, 
   IIF([Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS = 0,0, 
       [Add DVP Month].DevelopmentMonth/[Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS
      ),
       [EPMthd.8]
    ),
   IIF([Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS = 0,
   0, 
       [Add DVP Month].DevelopmentMonth/[Add DVP Month].COVMONTHS
    )
   )
 ))))))
 ) AS [EP%]
```

Comment: This is just a garbage post.

Comment: Agree. It's not what was asked and totally different syntax to SQL Server